# Looped Regressions in SPSS

Tags: regression, spss

I have a question, if I am using SPSS, and I have an dependent variable, call it y, and ten independent variables, call them x1 through x10, is there a method to run a loop to check all possible combinations of five variables against the dependent variable, and get a summary of the R^2 values of the model.  For instance:

```
y = independent; x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9,x10 = dependent
```

Regression:

```
y, (x1,x2,x3,x4,x5)
y, (x1,x2,x3,x4,x6) ...
```

so on and so on checking all combinations?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you want to do this rather than using a procedure like stepwise regression or best subsets?  What's the goal?  You will get 252 regressions.

But here's a bit of Python code to do this.  The spss.Submit line below should be indented.

```
begin program.  
import spss, itertools  

for v in itertools.combinations(['x1','x2','x3','x4','x5',\  
'x6','x7','x8','x9','x10'], 5):  
    spss.Submit("""REGRESSION /DEPENDENT = y /ENTER=%s""" % " ".join(v))  
end program.
```